# Add individual Axis Labels to PyQT chart in Python?

Tags: user-interface, label, pyqtgraph, pyside6

I'm in the final portion of my project and we just need to make a graph showing the number of shows and movies with their rating trend. I have 4 different bar graph items and I was wondering if there's a  way to add labels to each individual bar? For example here's one of the bars

```
y4 = [fourth]
x4 = [4.33]
bg4 = pg.BarGraphItem(x=x4, height=y4, width=0.2, brush='red', setLabel="Shows Down")
bg4.setX(0)
bg4.setY(0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a group of [TextItem](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/textitem.html) and set the bar as their parent:

```
text = pg.TextItem('Some bar', angle=90, color='#ffff00')
# reparent the item and make it a child of the bar
text.setParentItem(bg4)
# set the position to the x of the bar
text.setX(x4[0])
# use the x as left of the text and the y as vertical middle (referenced
# to the text orientation)
text.setAnchor(QPointF(0, .5))
```

<sup>Note that you don't need to create individual bars as long as they are part of the same group and share the same colors: just add the `x` and `height` as lists of their positions and values.</sup>

Comment: My only thing is the categories I have for the tour bars are: # movie titles with uptrend, # titles down trending, and same for tv. I'll definitely have to give that text thing a go. but how would I go about setting it up as a single plot?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with "how would I go about setting it up as a single plot"?

Comment: Apologies, when you set I don't need to make separate bars

Comment: @Demigas I'm not sure I'm understanding you, but if you're asking how to insert more bars with a single BarGraphItem: suppose you have to show 4 bars, at positions `[1, 2, 3, 4]` with values `[4.33, 1.22, 3.5, 2.1]`, then do `pg.BarGraphItem(x=positions, height=values, width=0.2)`.

Comment: Ohh okay. and then I can use your original answer to add labels to each bar?

Comment: @Demigas Yes, you need to add as many TextItems as bars, and set their X on each bar position.

Comment: Just for clarification, do I have to do a similar thing to set the title of the graph?

Comment: @Demigas that depends on what and how you need to show that, but this is off topic to this post, so I suggest you to carefully read the pyqtgraph documentation and eventually create a new question if you still can't find a solution.